# Remove plugins rss results Joomla

Tags: plugins, joomla, rss

I wonder how you can remove plugins syntax of the return results RSS joomla.

When viewing a feed section of Joomla, all items listed in that section in RSS format. If such articles contain a plugin, it displays the syntax of the plugin. I want to know is what is the way that syntax does not appear in the RSS.

Thanks for the help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that has to be coded into the plugin so that the code is removed. There is no default Joomla method to remove code from plugins that has not been processed in the content when the plugin does not replace it itself. Which is why I don't use the {-brackets for my plugins, but instead invent XML-tags, which are ignored by all RSS readers and browsers if the plugin is disabled.

Comment: My solution is modify the \libraries\joomla\document\feed\renderer\rss.php file, function named "render()". On this function, I remove the sintax from "description" file in the $data->items[$i] var.